# Como evitar que o Microsoft Outlook crie um link azul no html onde esta escrito www.algo.com

Tags: email

Estou fazendo um e-mail marketing com texto html e imagens. Em algumas partes do texto existe o endereço de uma empresa: www.empresa.com.br, que não deve ser um link, apenas texto.

Quando envio para teste, o gmail e outlook criam de forma automática um link azul clicável e sublinhado.

Consegui através de "css", "font face" e a "href=#" (tive de inserir para ele evitar o azul sublinhado) fazer com que o link fique sem a cor azul e sem sublinhado, apesar de linkar para nada. Mas quando encaminho este e-mail do outlook, ele cria o link novamente, para o endereço da empresa.

Existe algo que possa bloquear o outlook de criar esse link? Fazer com que ele leia o texto "www" e não interprete como link?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a propriedade **pointer-events** para desabilitar o evento de click.

```css
.link {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.empresa.com.br" class="link">www.empresa.com.br</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode por o link entre a tag `<pre>`

```
<pre><a href="http://www.empresa.com.br" class="link">www.empresa.com.br</a></pre>
```

mas por css seria mais dinamico no final, como a resposta do Laerte

Answer (score 1):

```css
.link {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#5a5a5a"><a href="#" style="color:#5a5a5a; text-decoration:none; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"  color="#5a5a5a">www.empresa.com.br</font></a></font>.
```